# Как получить значение

Tags: android, listview, java

Народ, привет. Помогите разобраться... я новенький в этом. Есть ListView который строится на основе  шаблона list_row. В list_row есть поля id (скрытое), title и info. ID содержит уникальный номер из базы. Если я знаю позицию нужного мне элемента в listview как мне взять ID из list_row мне нужно это значение. Позицию получаю путем долгого нажатия на элемент при котором всплывает контекст меню с кнопкой удалить.

```
<ListView       
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

---

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:text="Заголовок вопроса ... "
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="13dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
    android:text="Краткий вопрос ..."
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="11dip" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="00.00.0000 00:00"
    android:textColor="#464b50"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/question"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:contentDescription="@string/star"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Какой-то HTML-style подход с hidden-полями. Правильнее всё делается немного не так.

У вас есть адаптер `ListView`, в котором переопределяете метод `getItem`, а в нём уже возвращаете по позиции что вам угодно, что `id` записи, что какие-то более сложные структуры данных. Впрочем, в вашем случае, вполне хватит и простого переопределения `getItemId`, который умеет возвращать только `int`.

Ну а дальше либо в `onCreateContextMenu`, либо в `onContextItemSelected`, либо в установленном для `ListView OnItemLongClickListener` получаете нужные вам данные. В случае листенера - через `listView.getAdapter().getItem(position)` или `listView.getAdapter().getItemId(position)`, в случае использования одного из первых двух методов - через `AdapterContextMenuInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
>         View view, int position, long id) 
> {
>     final TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.id_item);
>     final String id = tv.getText();
> }
> ```

**id** содержит текст, который тебе нужен

**EDIT**

тогда сделай все намного проще:

**idsFromDB** - массив ID-шников записей из БД (инициализируй его при загрузке записей в **ListView**  из **BD**)

в **onItemLongClick()** берешь нужный тебе **ID** так: **idsFromDB[position]**

Comment: Вот такая конструкция
    
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
    .getMenuInfo();
  int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
  // check for selected option
  if (menuItemIndex == 0) {
   // user selected delete
   // delete the feed
   DataBaseHelper dbh = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

   
   // /dbh.deleteSite(info.position);
   
   // reloading same activity again
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   finish();
   startActivity(intent);
  }

  return true;
 }

Comment: что то я совсем не понял твой велосипед....обновил свой ответ